# ConcurrentModificationException when iterating on LinkedList

Tags: java, android

I am not sure why this part of my code causes error but I know that if I remove an item from a list and I am just iterating through it at the same time I get this exception. I read that syncronizing would be another idea, but it is not always the right apporach.  LogCat shows the ConcurrentModificationException for `while (sw.hasNext())` row. Please note that other part of my code has abosultely no effect on the Lists.

```
Iterator<Weapons> sw = Selected_Weapons.iterator();
                while (sw.hasNext()) {
                    Weapons www = sw.next();
                        if (www.getY()<648){

                            Iterator<Container> cit2 = Containers.iterator();
                            while (cit2.hasNext()) {
                                Container c = cit2.next();

                                if (c.getWeaponID()==www.id){
                                    c.setWeaponID(-1);
                                    c.setIsEmpty(true);
                                    Selected_Weapons.remove(www);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You're modifying the Selected_Weapons collection while it's being iterated.  The offending line is actually:

```
Selected_Weapons.remove(www);
```

In this case, you might want to iterate over the collection, and just keep track of which ones you want to remove after you've iterated over all of the items.

Comment: Or better yet, call `Iterator.remove()`. Then you don't need a separate collection.

Comment: I dont know how to accept answer when you write it in a comment but I'd accept it at least 5 times. Great and tricky solution! Thanks!

Comment: Because it went wrong 1 of 100 times today.. should I put sw.remove(); before the Selected_Weapons.remove(www) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using ConcurrentLinkedList?